# Allow Custom Role to edit a custom post type category

Tags: categories, user-roles

I have created a custom role, and have given access to edit a custom post (from another plugin).

This works, but the user with the custom role can edit the post, but not set the categories. They display but are readonly. If I also make the user a contributor, the categories are enabled.

Is there a way I can make the custom role be able to edit the categories?

Comment: You mentioned using another plugin to assign the ability to edit custom posts. Can you assign the capabilities to `manage_categories` using the same plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is no option to do that. The CPT does not have the option showing. Also, I may be wrong here, but doesn't manage_categories allow you to add/delete categories which are available. I just want to tick which categories the post applies to, from the list already setup.

Comment: You can use this[https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/] plugin to assign the capabilities/permissions to specific role. So for your custom role assign the capability `manage_category`.